# Hoisting issues in declaring variables then use them within each other in Google Script?

Tags: javascript

I've declared two variables  (link1 and link2) and use them within another declared variable (message). Then I created an if-statement where I use 'message' but I want to change the value of the two variables within the if-statement. In the end, I get a wrong output.

```
var link1, link2;
var messageFailed = "undefined";
var message = "Your first link: " + link1 + "Your second link: " + link2

if(true){
link1 = "Hello"
link2 = "World"
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
MailApp.sendEmail(messageFailed);
```

I can simply re-declare the 'message' variable within the if-statement, but I plan on using multiple if-statements so the code will end up looking really messy and a pain to change the 'message' text if needed. How would I go about changing the 'link1' and 'link2' variables after the 'message' variable is already declared?

Comment: To put it simply, you can't. You have assigned the value of message and it retains that value. It doesn't update like a placeholder. You could write a helper function here though.

Comment: Try placing the if true block before the "var message" line. Another thing that may be useful to know down the road is "undefined" and undefined (without the quotes) have very different meanings in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about changing the 'link1' and 'link2' variables after the 'message' variable is already declared?

You can change `link1` and `link2` but it will never affect the value of `message`, because you cannot go back in time. The string concatenation has already happened.

Instead you can create a function that generates the message based on the parameters it get passed:

```
function createMessage(link1, link2) {
  return "Your first link: " + link1 + "Your second link: " + link2
}

if(true){
  MailApp.sendEmail(createMessage("Hello", "World"));
}
```

That's how code reuse works. You are moving the parts that are *fixed* into a function and make the parts that are *variable* parameters of that function.

Answer (score 1):

So as I mentioned in a comment, you cannot because it is assigned to a value. What you could do though is write a super tiny helper function to format it.

```js
var link1 = "", link2 = "";
var message = () => {
  return "Your first link: " + link1 + " Your second link: " + link2;
}

if(true) {
    link1 = "waffles";
    link2 = "juicyfruit";
    console.log(message());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `message` you're calculating your result and assigning it then. Changing those variables afterwards does not change the string that was calculated when you assigned `message`. You need to create your message after you finish changing your variables.